# How to improve Geofencing reliability?

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services, geofencing

In my Android app I use geofencing features of Google Play Services.

For example a user drives a car (so his device has GPS signal), then the user stops and adds geofence for current location (with 300m radius), enters a building (the device loses GPS and guesses location using the cell network), then the user drives to next location. The app should calculate how much time the user spent in the building. I noticed that geofence exit events are quite unreliable in such scenarios. Very often there are no geofence exit events at all.

I wonder how to improve reliability of exit events. For example additionality to geofencing, the app can use activity recognition. When a user starts driving a car then the app can turn GPS on for a 15 seconds. So geofencing gets more accurate location data, thus so it can produce more accurate exit events.

Is this idea is reasonable? Maybe Google Play Services already does tricks like that.

Comment: 'activity recognition.' ? What is that? 'the app can turn GPS on'. No. Apps can't.

Comment: 'GPS on for a 15 seconds. So geofencing gets more accurate location data,'. The gps should always be on as only that is accurate.

Comment: @greenapps 1. search for ActivityRecognitionApi 2. Using LocationManager and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION an app can turn the GPS on.

Comment: The issue you get with using the activity recognition for geofencing is that it becomes a much larger power draw than just Google geofence alone.  Not to mention that the activity detection is slow as well.  There are SDKs out there that are trying to solve this issue now (www.pathsense.com is one of them).  However if you don't mind the power draw, you don't need 15 seconds of GPS, just request for updates at a timed interval when you get IN_VEHICLE detection.  Google's geofence appears to listen to the passive provider, so just a single update should help it get a little better.